# how to prerender or ssr vue application?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering, prerender

I'm working on lagacy project(laravel vue webpack.mix), which has a very poorly built architecture and no Vue logic.
Now I have a task - to set up an SEO audit for normal indexing by the search system`s.

I don’t know anything about this topic and found two options

1. server-sider-rendering - I tried to use the `inertia.js` library, but I had an error like 'undefined variable $page' (maybe someone knows something about this).
   Well, I decided to move away from this idea
2. prerender - I found a topic in the vue docs about prerender-spa-plugin, but again I had problems.
   everything seems to be connected, but pre-rendering does not work
   I still have, if I use curl 'address', the browser returns  instead of html markup, which, as I understand it, prevents SEO robots from indexing the page properly
   and in my dist directory no html files, only js and css
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm6Cf.png)

my webpack.mix.js file

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
var path = require('path')
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin-next')



/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
mix.setPublicPath('dist');

mix.js("resources/assets/js/app.js", "public/assets/js")
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
                // Required - The path to the webpack-outputted app to prerender.
                staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                // Required - Routes to render.
                routes: ['/'],
            })
        ],
    })
    .js("resources/assets/js/connect-vue.js", "public/assets/js")
    .js("resources/assets/js/connect-footer-vue.js", "public/assets/js")
    .vue()
    .sourceMaps();
mix.js("resources/assets/js/index.js", "public/assets/js")
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
                // Required - The path to the webpack-outputted app to prerender.
                staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                // Required - Routes to render.
                routes: ['/'],
            })
        ],
    })
    .js("resources/assets/js/front/gallery/cart.js", "public/assets/js/front")
    .js("resources/assets/js/email/send-email.js", "public/assets/js/front")
    .js("resources/assets/js/front/user/user-info.js", "public/assets/js/front")
    .js("resources/assets/js/front/user/orders.js", "public/assets/js/front")
    .js(
        "resources/assets/js/front/user/orderModels.js",
        "public/assets/js/front"
    )
    .js(
        "resources/assets/js/front/user/user-address.js",
        "public/assets/js/front"
    )
    .js(
        "resources/assets/js/front/gallery/gallery.js",
        "public/assets/js/front"
    );
mix.sass("resources/assets/sass/app.scss", "public/assets/css").sourceMaps();
mix.sass("resources/assets/sass/app-admin.scss", "public/assets/css").sass(
    "resources/assets/sass/front/wishlist.scss",
    "public/assets/css"
);

//User scss
mix.sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/front/dashboard.scss",
        "public/assets/css/front"
    )
    .sass("resources/assets/sass/front/login.scss", "public/assets/css/front")
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/front/contacts.scss",
        "public/assets/css/front"
    )
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/front/user-info.scss",
        "public/assets/css/front"
    )
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/front/user-orders.scss",
        "public/assets/css/front"
    )
    .sass("resources/assets/sass/front/gallery.scss", "public/assets/css/front")
    .sass("resources/assets/sass/front/cart.scss", "public/assets/css/front")
    .sass("resources/assets/sass/front/home.scss", "public/assets/css/front")
    .sass("resources/assets/sass/front/footer.scss", "public/assets/css/front")
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/front/client-model.scss",
        "public/assets/css/front"
    )
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/front/card-model.scss",
        "public/assets/css/front"
    )
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/front/user-model.scss",
        "public/assets/css/front"
    )
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/front/submit-material.scss",
        "public/assets/css/front"
    )
    .sass("resources/assets/sass/front/rtl.scss", "public/assets/css/front");

//Admin scss
mix.sass("resources/assets/sass/admin/style.scss", "public/assets/css/admin")
    .sass("resources/assets/sass/admin/order.scss", "public/assets/css/admin")
    .sass(
        "resources/assets/sass/admin/material.scss",
        "public/assets/css/admin"
    );

//Admin Js
mix.js("resources/assets/js/app-admin.js", "public/assets/js").sourceMaps();
mix.js("resources/assets/js/admin/dashboard.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/order.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/model.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/offer.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/material.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/client-model.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/cura-crush.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/profile.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/setting.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/user.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/request.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/promotion-code.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/coupon.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/tag.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/review.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/faq.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/payment.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/cms.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/sections.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/admin.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js("resources/assets/js/admin/analitics.js", "public/assets/js/admin")
    .js(
        "resources/assets/js/admin/create-model-field.js",
        "public/assets/js/admin"
    )
    .js(
        "resources/assets/js/admin/edit-model-field.js",
        "public/assets/js/admin"
    );
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

I suspect this is due to the terrible structure of Vue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGzCe.png)
1 page = 1 vue component in blade.php file

example

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('page-title', 'Gallery')

@push('styles')
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/front/cart.css?v=' . config('app.version')) }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush

@push('scripts')

@endpush

@section('content')
    <gallery-component></gallery-component>
{{--    <div class="new-pagination">{{ $models->links("pagination::bootstrap-4") }}</div>--}}

    @include('front.gallery.modals.modal_cart')

    <script>
        let userId = {!! auth()->user() ? auth()->id() : 0  !!},
            categories = {!! json_encode($categories) !!},
            autorizetion = {!! auth()->user() ? 0 : 1  !!}

    </script>

@endsection
```

I think I just don’t understand something and am missing something basic.
I will be very glad for advice and help.

i tried to setup server side rendering with inertia.js, but i had a errors with it
and now im trying to setup prerender vue with prerender-spa-plugin, but i dont know how i can recognize, if prerender working))

Comment: I'm not expert of ssr, but based on what i know. This seems to be complexe because Vue is used in first attention to be a client side. It seems there is a way to achieve that https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html.

But normaly if you want to use Vuejs and have ssr, you use nuxtJs who is designed for this.
https://nuxt.com/

Comment: @RaphaelRlt Yeah, ssr on native vue - its a bad idea, but it`s so big and legacy project and i dont have enough time for transfer to nuxt.js.
Now im trying setup prerender, but this is also problematic for now(((